# RestTemplate using SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory throwing I/O Authentication Error

Tags: java, resttemplate

I need to connect some Rest API through Spring RestTemplate using proxy. I have observed some interesting behavior on Java6 and Java7.
 Below is my code look like

Bean Defination :

```
<bean id="myRestTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="objectMapper" ref="myJacksonObjectMapper" />
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                        <list>
                            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON"/>
                            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN"/>
                            <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.http.MediaType.TEXT_HTML"/>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="requestFactory">
            <bean class="my.util.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactoryWithTimeout">
                <property name="connectTimeout" value="500">
                </property>
                <property name="readTimeout" value="500">
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Java Call :

```
 SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("myproxy", "8080");
                Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, address);
                simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
                restTemplate.setRequestFactory(simpleClientHttpRequestFactory);

ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("restapiurl", requestType, requestEntity, responseClass);
```

Code works well on Java7 but throws I/O Exception Authentication failure . I have added required certificate in cacerts of both jre.

```
-I/O error: Authentication failure; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Authentication failure
```

Please help me to resolve issue on java 6.

Comment: Does your proxy requires authentication (i.e. login and password)? If so, you may consider providing the `-Dhttp.proxyUser=user` and `-Dhttp.proxyPassword=password` settings to your JVM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RestTemplate using SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory throwing I/O Authentication Error on Java6 but not on Java7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310557/resttemplate-using-simpleclienthttprequestfactory-throwing-i-o-authentication-er)